# R if function on a dataset with three options

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am currently trying to apply this set of equations, and so I would not have to do them by hand 52 different times, I tried to automatically calculate and assign them to the dataframe with R. However, as I have been using R for not even a month I am struggling a little.

The dataset looks like this (an example):

```
tooth   type    Yang    De_Angelis
------------------------------------
1   incisor 24.08529459 
2   incisor 35.09026054 
3   cuspid  34.81029915 46.91019398
4   cuspid  33.72315404 45.37837099
5   incisor 47.25024012 
6   incisor 45.64875804 
7   incisor 36.67472354 
8   incisor 47.1395039  
9   incisor 51.33480654 
10  cuspid  32.47988556 43.62656509
11  premolar34.78631823 
12  incisor 40.28305809 
13  cuspid  29.87469343 39.95576424
14  cuspid  26.85494824 35.7008446
15  incisor 32.82060901 
16  premolar31.9208201  
17  incisor 43.85520278
```

I have at this moment a set of three equations, each for the particular type of tooth, that I would like the code to run and to connect it as another column to the dataset (like I did with the previous methods). The equations are as follows:

```
Star

    incisor 51.08 - 499.01*PV_TV
    canine 49.1 - 219.36*PV_TV
    premolar 38.11 - 302.53*PV_TV
```

PV_TV is an already established line of numerical values being pulled from another dataset, I have checked it and it works perfectly, so the problem is not there.

```
age$Star <- function(x) {
  
  if(age$type == "incisor") {print(51.08 - 499.01*PV_TV)}
  if(age$type == "cuspid") {print(49.1 - 219.36*PV_TV)}
  if(age$type == "premolar") {print(38.11 - 302.53*PV_TV)}  

}
```

This is one of the versions of the code I tried, I know that the problem is probably in the function (x) but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any advice? Should I be using completely different function? I tried `ifelse`, but that did not seem to be the right one either.

Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: your function is incorrect. You are passing in `x` but it is not used anywhere. Also, are you trying to create a new variable?

Comment: Okay, does that mean that I need to deffine the x before? I tried to do that as age$type but that did not go anywhere.
I am trying to create a new collumn for the dataset, the values of which will correspond to its type equation. Like if the "cell" is in a row where the type is incisor, it will use equation a, if cuspid then b, if premolar then c.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, using `library(dplyr)`

```
your_data |>
  mutate(Star = case_when(
    type == "incisor" ~ 51.08 - 499.01 * Yang, 
    type == "canine" ~ 49.1 - 219.36 * Yang,
    type == "premolar" ~ 38.11 - 302.53 * Yang 
  ))
```

If you're doing this on several different data sets and don't want to copy/paste that code, that would be a good reason to write a function, which we could do like this:

```
compute_star = function(type, x) {
  ifelse(type == "incisor", 51.08 - 499.01 * x,
    ifelse(type == "canine", 49.1 - 219.36 * x,
      ifelse(type == "premolar", 38.11 - 302.53 * x, NA)
    )
  )
}

## then use it like this:
your_data$star = compute_star(type = your_data$type, x = your_data$Yang)
```

Note that when I define the function I assign it to a function name that I later use, not assigning the function directly to a column. Also notice that the only variables used inside the function definition are the arguments passed into the function.

Comment: Thanks, so it was ifelse!

I ran the code and calculated the first two rows myself to check, however none of the results fit and none of the cuspids were calculated.

This is the cude i used: 

compute_star = function(type, x) {
  ifelse(type == "incisor", 51.08 - 499.01 * PT_TV,
         ifelse(type == "canine", 49.1 - 219.36 * PT_TV,
                ifelse(type == "premolar", 38.11 - 302.53 * PT_TV, NA)
         )
  )
}

age$star = compute_star(type = age$type, x = age$Yang)

I think the problem is in the x = age$Yang and that I probably dont understand how the x in fx works.

Comment: Fixed it!! I did not notice that the equations list i coped used the different name fir cuspids, so thats why they did not compute. And when I deleted the x = age$Yang from the end and x from the begining, basically deleted the whole x it started counting just according to the type.
Thank you very much for your help, I think that I am finally starting to understand the function...function xD.